# SQL LIMIT expression

Tags: mysql

Users:

```
UserID | UserNick
3      | Joe
23     | Peter
4      | Mary
```

Messages:

```
FromUserID | theMSG
3          | Hi
3          | What' up?
23         | asdfg
23         | OK...
4          | Hi, this is Mary
```

I  have a query that gives the following result:

```
UserID | Message
1      | Hello
1      | How are ya?
2      | yadda yadda
5      | Cool.
5      | I didn't know that.
```

I now want to limit the result. Not by the number of rows I get back, by the number of different users from whom I want to see the messages.

"Give me three messages of the first 2 users"

```
UserID | Message
1      | Hello
1      | How are ya?
2      | yadda yadda
```

But if I write `LIMIT 2`, it will give me only

```
UserID | Message
1      | Hello
1      | How are ya?
```

How do I achieve what I want? What's the keyword I need?

Comment: Do you need something more eloquent than WHERE `UserID` <= '2'?

Comment: This won't work because I don't know in advance what a user's id is.

Comment: Do you need a solution where you can ask "give me the latest X messages from the first Y users", and do you then want X messages from each of the Y users, or should the sum of messages be Y? If the numbers are always the same you can perhaps get away with a `UNION` question, but I'm not sure you'll ever get away with a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following query. It gives you options to select `first n` unique users or `last n` unique users. Use `ASC` for first or `DESC` for last n users.

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE UserID IN (
           SELECT DISTINCT UserID 
           FROM messages 
           ORDER BY UserID ASC/DESC 
           LIMIT 2
)
LIMIT 2
```

1. Inner Limit defines the number of unique users you want to select.
2. Outer Limit definesthe number of messages you wish to see from users

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a nested query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE UserID IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM messages ORDER BY UserID LIMIT 2)
```

but without knowing the table structure it is difficult to say more.

The idea is:

- get the users you want in nested query
- get their messages with outer query

Comment: Note: This will return all messages from those two users, which with time could become a lot of them. And if he wants the first three messages from each of the users then `LIMIT 6` won't have the desired effect either. But it's probably as close as you can get without doing several and more advanced queries.

Comment: ... and it probably needs a `DISTINCT` in the nested query.

Comment: @SilverSnake I agree on both things you said. I just wanted to give him an idea how to resolve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can get those results with:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE UserID IN(1, 2)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE UserID BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```